# IPython code migration from Python 2 to Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.3, jupyter-notebook

Because of SciPy, I have stuck with Python 2 even though I would like to move to Python 3. As most of my research work is data analysis and modelling, I have used the IPython HTML notebook in my day-to-day work. However, that means I've become used to the Python 2 syntax (e.g. `print x`), which frequently comes up in my sanity-checking steps.

Now that SciPy seems to be Python 3-compatible (please correct me if I'm wrong), I'd like to migrate over from Python 2 to Python 3.

However, that means most of my IPython notebooks will be riddled with Python 2 `print` statements, which will yield tons of errors each time I re-run analyses through them.

So here's my question: Is 2to3 capable of modifying the IPython HTML notebooks? Logistical challenge: I have ~30-40 of them now, scattered in different project folders. If 2to3 is not the correct solution, should I do something else?

Comment: You are correct that there's no automated tool that works on the HTML notebooks yet. This is discussed in the issue tracker here: https://github.com/swcarpentry/bc/issues/107 The .ipynb files are text files that you could parse with a script that takes care of this 2to3 conversion, though it may not necessarily be trivial. The thread indicates that the issue will be revisited in 2014.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this script [2to3_nb.py](https://gist.github.com/takluyver/c8839593c615bb2f6e80). Just run it like this: `python 2to3_nb.py <path_to_folder_containing_notebooks>`.

Comment: Suppose I have a full project that has notebooks coded in Python 2.7. I want to convert all of them to Python 3.

If I run: `python 2to3_nb.py <my_project_folder>`, will it convert and replace all the notebooks in <my_project_folder> with Python 3 code?